# OpenSSL API Read private key in DER format instead of PEM

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, private-key

I am looking for an equivalent of `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey()` that also returns a `RSA` struct but gets passed a pointer to the private key in `DER` format instead of `PEM`.
I could not find anything in the OpenSSL documentation though.

Comment: that documentation is pretty skimpy and all mixed together with the command line docs ... so hard to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [d2i_PrivateKey_bio()](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/apps.c#L1041) function.